# Convert date "1472120311221" to datetime format in H2 Database?

Tags: h2

I am using H2 database where I want to convert date in specified date format. I tried everything but wasn't able to get any result.

Input: `-date "1472120311221"` Output: `YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS`

Comment: Please be explicit about what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timestamp seems to be in milliseconds, not in seconds.

Please use the following snippet:

```
select DATEADD('SECOND', 1472120311221/1000, DATE '1970-01-01');
-- 2016-08-25 11:18:31.0
```

Once adapted according to your exact needs, this becomes:

```
select FORMATDATETIME(
  DATEADD('SECOND', 1472120311221/1000, DATE '1970-01-01'),
  'YYYY-dd-MM HH:mm:ss'
);
-- 2016-25-08 11:18:31
```

Comment: I tried it now with H2 2.0.206 and there is no need to convert to seconds anymore DATEADD('MILLISECOND', <epoch millis>, DATE '1970-01-01')